# Open pdf in <DIV> found in another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have two html pages, "page1.html" and "page2.html".

page1.html contains a css menu list which will link to page2.html. Part of sample code is below:

```
 <div class="menu"> 

 <ul>   
     <li><a href="page1.html">page1</a></li>
     <li><a href="page2.html">page2</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="page2.html" onclick="displaypdf1();" >pdf1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" onclick ="displaypdf2();">pdf2</a></li>
```

when click on one of the link , the  tag in "page2.html". However i cannot achieve this. it does not load the pdf correctly. 
displaypdf1() javascript function as below:

```
function display_cover(){
    var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 
url: 'Cover.pdf',
pdfOpenParams: { 
view: 'FitB', 
viewrect: 
'0,0,1000,900',
pagemode: 'none', 
scrollbars: '1', 
toolbar: '1', 
statusbar: '1', 
messages: '1', 
navpanes: '1' }
    }).embed('pdf_display'); 
}
```

i'm using pdfObject for opening pdf.
In short i wish to open a pdf file through page1.html css menu.PDF will then be displayed on page2.html in a  tag How can i achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ajax as follows:

***Page 1 HTML***

```
<style>  
     .wrapper {background-color: #cdcdcd; width: 100%; height: 700px }
     object {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
     #target { width: 600px; height: 650px; }
     input { position:relative; left:20px; }
 </style> 

 <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="button" value="Go">
      <div id="target"></div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

The button is the trigger,. It can be triggered with an a ref or even a list item from a nav menu. 
The id target can be placed in any page as well. I made it so that it displays in this same page but you can change it as you please.

***Page 1 JS/JQUERY***

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(function($){
            $('input').click(function(){
                 $('#target').load('page2.html');
                 });
            });
   </script>
```

Hopefully this works for you

***Page 2 HTML***
This is the PDF in an object element that will be loaded as an external page inside your page without refreshing the page or in another page if you choose that.

```
    <object data="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="50%" height="700px">
         alt : <a href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf">page2.pdf</a>
    </object>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, however this opens to a new window instead. What i want to achieve is to load the pdf into a <div> tag found on another webpage. Is that achievable?

Comment: Sure, it can be done with ajax. Let me see what I have in my PC. I swear I did this already. I have to step in a meeting. I'll help later if no one else already answered

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your suggestions and it works wonderfully on internet explorer but not chrome. Something wrong with .load. The page has displayed blank. Based on the concept that you had given, i managed to solve my problem!

JS/JQUERY

```
//script for display Cover.pdf
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#input').click(function(){   
    document.getElementById('project_details').innerHTML = 
    '<object type="application/pdf" data="pdf1.pdf" width=1000px height="810px" >  
    </object>'
    });
});
```

I created a sample based on your idea with the JS above and it works. Hopefully this will be useful for someone else. Thanks lotusms.